# How to set up "Bindings" adf?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new to adf. I am developing a module in an existing application. The modules are similar and there are not big differences. When setting up the .jsff file, I can't set up "Bindings" in any way. There are "Bindings" in the screenshot - this is copied from another module to my new module, since it is similar. Please advise what needs to be done to set them up. Screenshots attached.

P.S. Screenshots are temporarily unavailable. Error on the server

Comment: I added several questions to your equal question here https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4504741/how-to-set-up-bindings#latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was given in the question at https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4504741/how-to-set-up-bindings#latest

In summary, it turned out that the pageDef file that holds the bindings was not created. The easiest way to create one is to drag something from a datacontrol onto the page and drop it there. This will create the pageDef file needed.